# How to delete nonconsecutive lines in text using RegEx?

Tags: regex, notepad++, duplicates

I use the following expression in Notepad++ to delete duplicate lines:

```
^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$
```

The problems are:

1. It is only for single word lines, if there is space in a line it won't work.
2. It is only for consecutive duplicate lines.

Is there a solution (preferably regular expression or macro) to delete duplicate lines in a text that contains space, and that are nonconsecutive?

Comment: Please post what you tried, the text you are working on and the expected output.

Comment: Ok, let me help: does your file look like `Line1\r\nLine1\r\nLine1\r\nLine1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 2`, and you want to turn it to `Line1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 2`? Did you try any regex so far? Or any plugins?

Answer (score 4):

Since no one is interested, I will post what I think you need.

> delete duplicate lines in a text that contains space, and that are nonconsecutive

I assume you have text having, say duplicate lines `My Line One and some text` and `My Line Two and more text`:

```
My Line One and some text
My Line One and some text
My Line Two and more text
My Line One and some text
My Line Two and more text
```

These duplicate lines are not all consecutive (only the first two).

So, you can remove duplicate lines by running this search and replace:

```
^(.+)\r?\n(?=[\s\S]*?^\1$)
```

Replace with empty string.

Regex note: `^` and `$` are treated as line start/end anchors by default, so we only match one line and capture it with `^(.+)$`. Then we match the newline symbol (any OS style) with `\r?\n`. The look-ahead `(?=...)` checks if there is any text (with `[\s\S]*?`) after our line under inspection with the same contents (with the `^\1$` where `\1` is a backreference to the line text captured).

[image]

Comment: I used this one that works only on consecutive lines: 
^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$
Regex you posted works! thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Instead of `\r?\n`, you may use `\R` to match any line breaks (`CRLF`, `CR` and `LF`s).