# Regex (Replace)? to match only first and distincted occurences

Tags: c#, regex

I've got a problem with Regex. Basically I've got a word document with headers which contains date.
Prepared an algorithm which will substract data from date to date and there is no problem when every date is only once in file, but when I have date at beginning of every page this dividing doesn't work as it should. I've tried to use regex with (?!) negative lookahead at the end of the pattern
like `(?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>\d{2,4})(?![\s\S]*\1)`
but it's matching only the last of dates, and if I have 3 pages dedicated for one day, it is only matching from the last one. Is there any possibility to create regex which will match only first and distincted occurence? So if I have one date 3 times it will match the first one and data will be divided correctly? Another option is that I can replace everything in string which is not the first date.

> Regex could be actually like

```
 (?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>\d{2,4})
```

> File:

```
 13-08-2020
 data day1 
 13-08-2020 
 data day1  
 13-08-2020 
 data day1 
 14-08-2020
 data day2
```

And I would like to have that regex with will only match with first occurence of 13-08-2020 and then first of 14-08-2020, or replace dates with blank space so then it will looks like

```
13-08-2020
data day1
data day1
data day1
14-08-2020
data day2
```

Comment: Perhaps it is an option to do it in 2 steps. First match from the starting date till the next line that start with a date other than the start date. Then in the replacement, remove all the lines that start with a date. See https://ideone.com/Bn3oYa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a lookbehind. The following regex uses a positive lookbehind and matches any dates that have already occurred before:

```
(?<=[\s\S]*^(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{2,4})$[\s\S]*)(^\1$)
```

Here's a full C# example (which you can e.g. test at https://dotnetfiddle.net/) that replaces all dates for which the lookbehind is a match with an empty string:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string myText = "13-08-2020\n"
                      + "data day1\n"
                      + "13-08-2020\n"
                      + "data day1\n"
                      + "13-08-2020\n"
                      + "data day1\n"
                      + "14-08-2020\n"
                      + "data day2";
        string pattern = @"(?<=[\s\S]*^(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{2,4})$[\s\S]*)(^\1$)";
        string CleanedString = Regex.Replace(myText, pattern, "", RegexOptions.Multiline);  
        Console.Write(CleanedString); 
    }
}
```

Result:

```
13-08-2020
data day1

data day1

data day1
14-08-2020
data day2
```

Please note that this expression in this form only works in multiline mode, i.e. when "^" and "$" match *line* start/ending and not *string* start/ending.

I based this solution on [How to delete nonconsecutive lines in text using RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023479/how-to-delete-nonconsecutive-lines-in-text-using-regex)